# Qiskit DensityMatrix.from_instruction when snapshots are present

Tags: qiskit, density-matrix

I have a quantum circuit in which I apply snapshots like this during setup:

```
    for qubit_index in range(0, num_qubits):
        
        if qubit_index < num_qubits-1:
            next_qubit_index = qubit_index + 1
            snapshot_name_string = "snapshot_" + str(qubit_index) + "_" + str(next_qubit_index)
            print("--- Setting " + snapshot_name_string)
            quantum_circuit.snapshot(snapshot_name_string, qubits = [qubit_index,next_qubit_index])
```

This so I can compute the amplitudes of sub-systems. For example, if I have 10 qubits, but want to get probabilities of only the 3rd and fourth qubit being in their states (00, 01, 10, 11), I use:

```
result = execute(quantum_circuit, backend, shots=1).result()
snapshots = result.data()['snapshots']['statevector'][snapshot_name_string][0].tolist()
```

I need the probabilities to correctly sample projective measurements before applying Clifford gates to (qubit_index,next_qubit_index) during the evolution. However, later on in the evolution when I try to analyze the density matrix:

```
rho = qi.DensityMatrix.from_instruction(quantum_circuit)
# just note I then go on to compute the partial trace
reduced_rho = qi.partial_trace(rho, subsystem_range)
```

I now get an error **QiskitError: 'Cannot apply Instruction: snapshot'** from qi.DensityMatrix.from_instruction(). The density matrix from_instruction was working fine before I implemented the snapshots (when I was randomly selected a projective measurement based on uniform distribution rather than based on amplitudes).

Does anyone know how I can reconcile the DensityMatrix with the snapshots? I don't see a DensityMatrix parameter that just says 'use the whole system instead of a snapshot.' Also if their is an easy/better way to get amplitudes of sub-system states without snapshots that would be perfectly acceptable answer as well!

<thank|you!>

Answer (score 1):

Since you already executed the circuit and get the snapshots you want, a workaround is to remove the `snapshot` instructions before calling `DensityMatrix.from_instruction`:

```
from itertools import count
for index, instruction in zip(count(len(circ.data) - 1, -1), reversed(circ.data)):
    print(index, instruction[0].name)
    if instruction[0].name == 'snapshot':
        del circ.data[index]

DensityMatrix.from_instruction(circ)
```

You may also replace them with [`Barrier`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.Barrier.html) instructions or [`I`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.IGate.html) gates:

```
from qiskit.circuit import Barrier
quantum_circuit.data = [(Barrier(_inst[0].num_qubits), _inst[1], _inst[2]) if _inst[0].name == 'snapshot' else _inst for _inst in quantum_circuit.data]

DensityMatrix.from_instruction(circ)
```